# Angular Firebase startAfter for paginated queries not working as expected

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have been looking at other posts regarding this topic, mainly for React and reading on how to use [paginated queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#use_a_document_snapshot_to_define_the_query_cursor) but am struggling to understand what I am missing. I want to do an infinite scroll using ngx-infinite-scroll. What I want to happen is on first load the app loads in x number of books from my firebase firestore. Then on page load it loads in next x number of books

I have the first part working and I have the second part working but it always seems to return the same data set. I have tried several different ways but here is what I currently have trying to debug this by breaking it apart really explicitly.

```
  constructor(private readonly db:  AngularFirestore,private readonly firebaseApp: FirebaseApp) { }
  public listVisible:any;

  getBooks(): Observable<DocumentData[]> {
    return collectionData(query(collection(this.firebaseApp.firestore(), "Bookshelf"), orderBy("year_read", "desc"), limit(5))).pipe(
      tap((data) => this.listVisible = data[data.length - 1])
    )

  }
  getMoreBooks(){
    console.log(this.listVisible) //shows the last item of the array
   return collectionData(query(collection(this.firebaseApp.firestore(), "Bookshelf"), orderBy("year_read", "desc"), startAfter(this.listVisible), limit(5)))
  }
```

and then in the component

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
//first 5 books in the console log statement
 this.bookService.getBooks().subscribe((data) => {console.log(data)});
  }


  onScroll(){
  
//the console log here is always the same 5 books from above
    this.bookService.getMoreBooks().pipe(tap(console.log)).subscribe((data) ....)
```

can anyone help me understand this? I know this code is not ideal again just been trying to hard code/  break things apart to understand why the startAfter() is not working

Answer (score 0):

Your (initial) `getBooks` method set `listVisible`, which ensures that `getMoreBooks` then starts after the last book of the first page when you call it.

But calling `getMoreBooks` never sets the `listVisible` variable, which is required to ensure the next `getMoreBooks` will go to the next page, so you always end up with the second page of books when you call `getMoreBooks`.

The solution is to update `listVisible` inside `getMoreBooks`.

Comment: Hey Frank - Thanks for reaching out. I did try that by updating my code but its still not working and I think I know why. So on getMoreBooks I add a pipe and that the data returned is always the same book - so thus when I tap it and reassign listVisible (i know I cannot spell) it effectively stays the same

Comment: I am not an Angular expert, so can't give you the exact code needed. --- But does the explanation of why you only ever get to page 2 in my answer clear? And is it also clear why you need to set `listVisible` in `getMoreBooks` in order to ever get to further pages?

Comment: Hey Frank,
Yeah what you are saying makes sense but what I struggle with is even hard coding values I am unable to achieve what I am looking for. Wondering if the wrapper that AngularFire puts around firebase sdk?